# Spring not picking up RestController endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have my spring project setup as shown below, but I am getting a 404 on the /custom endpoint. All answers I've found similar to this problem highlighted that the controller layer needs to be in a package below the project layer however I have it set out like this so I'm unsure why Spring isn't recognising the endpoint.

```
package com.myproject.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("custom")
public class CustomPathController {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> test() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

```
package com.myproject;

import com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.EnableMetrics;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@EnableMetrics
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyProject {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyProject.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the structure of your project ? Maybe your controller class isn't scanned and instantiated by Spring.

Comment: I tried it with an equal package structure, just different names and it worked, which dependencies are contained in the pom ?

Comment: @user3240544 I tried adding ComponentScan("com.myproject") to the runner class and Intellij is telling me it's a redundant annotation as SpringBootApplication is applying the annotation

Comment: @dariosicily lombok, spring boot starter jpa, postgresql, spring-boot-configuration-processor, spring-boot-starter-actuator, spring-boot-starter-logging, spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: I'm using [serving-web-content](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/), I think the error it is due to the absence of  `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must have been a port clash as a PC restart has fixed the issue